# Append text to a found cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple spreadsheets with a **hours** as text in Column A and and a running sum total beside in in Column B.

The row in which we have the hours listed varies which is why I run a *find* to get its location.

We run a rolling sum (=5+3+6+8) to have a visual cue as in, the individual worked out 5 hours the first day, 3 hours the next, 6 the next etc.

I'm trying to build a formula that would be able to add to that string and complete the formula so I would see the total of the formula in the spreadsheet and the individual additions in its contents.

So far I have something to find the cell and locate it but I can't get it to append to the end in its contents.

Consider the *thours* variable,

```
Sub findhours()
 Dim hours As Range
    Set hours =     Application.Workbooks("vbstest.dec17").Worksheets("sheet1").Cells.Find("hours")
 Dim thours As Range
    Set thours =     Application.Workbooks("vbstest.dec17").Worksheets("sheet2").Cells.Find("hours")

 Dim z As Integer
  Dim zh As Integer

    z = hours.Column
    zh = thours.Column

Dim x As Integer
Dim xh As Integer

    x = hours.Row
    xh = thours.Row


   Application.Workbooks("vbstest.dec17").Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(x, z).Offset(0, 1).Value = 5
```

The above satisfies hours for daily, by thours needs a little extra. How do i take something like:

```
Range(zh, xh + 1)
```

which is a string of addition (=5+3+6+8) and be able to add to that addition to get something like (=5+3+6+8+4) and then be able to return to this macro to keep adding to this formula? Most of my attempts have returned its value (22).

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like `Cells(xh + 1, zh).Formula = Cells(xh + 1, zh).Formula & "+5"`?

Answer (score 1):

I can't quite figure out which cell contains what in your question but, assuming that `Cells(r1, c1).Value` contains the current total hours worked, and `Cells(r2, c2).Formula` contains a formula that calculated the previous total hours worked, then you can update the formula to reflect the current hours worked by something like:

```
Cells(r2, c2).Formula = Cells(r2, c2).Formula & "+" & _
                        (Cells(r1, c1).Value - Cells(r2, c2).Value)
```

---

I think I have worked out your sheet layout, so I think the formula becomes

```
With Application.Workbooks("vbstest.dec17").Worksheets("sheet2")
  .Cells(xh, zh + 1).Formula = .Cells(xh, zh + 1).Formula & "+" & _
     (Application.Workbooks("vbstest.dec17").Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(x, z + 1).Value - _
     .Cells(xh, zh + 1).Value)
End With
```